# How to delete blank lines from CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file using `:` as delimiter and contains blank lines. My CSV file looks likes-

```
P Data Usage (Bytes):        640
P Inst Usage (Bytes):        13322
P Local Patch Match:         105
P Global Patch Match:        20

V Data Usage (Bytes):        312
V Inst Usage (Bytes):        972
V Local Patch Match:         24
V Global Patch Match:        1

U UOP Usage:                 352
U Patch Match:               51
```

I want to remove blank lines from this file and I want to store it in the same file. I want to use all the values after `:` for updating Excel table.

How to remove blank lines from the file because if I am trying to read the file it is reading only top 4 lines and not reading any further line. I want to store every integer value in each row in a list like -

```
a = ['640', '13322', '105', '20', '312', '972', '24', ..., '51']
```

Comment: That's not really a CSV file. A CSV file format contains rows with a fixed number of columns with data that are delimited by a single character. Your file doesn't match that description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a CSV file, so don't try to treat it as one. CSV specifically means a file consisting of rows of columns, where all rows have the same number of columns and the columns are delimited by a single character (usually a comma or a tab).

There is no need to delete the lines from your source file if all you needed was those first 4 values for your code either.

Just loop over the lines in the file, split each line by *whitespace*, and if the resulting list is not empty, take the last value:

```
numbers = []
with open(filename) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        data = line.split()
        if data:
            numbers.append(data[-1])
```

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with no arguments splits on *arbitrary length whitespace*, including tabs, spaces and newlines, with any whitespace at the start and end ignored.

When a line is *empty* the `line` string will be `'\n'`, and splitting such a line results in an empty list. If there is anything other than whitespace on a line, you get a list of strings for each non-whitespace section:

```
>>> '\n'.split()
[]
>>> 'P Inst Usage (Bytes):        13322\n'.split()
['P', 'Inst', 'Usage', '(Bytes):', '13322']
```

Because your file has the numbers you want at the end of each line, taking the last element (with `[-1]`) gets you all the numbers.

If you only need the top four such lines, test the `len(numbers)` result:

```
numbers = []
with open(filename) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        data = line.split()
        if data:
            numbers.append(data[-1])
            if len(numbers) == 4:
                break
```

The `break` stops the `for` loop, and when you exit the `with` statement, the file will be closed automatically.

If you do ever need to skip blank lines, just test if `line.strip()` is truthy; `str.strip()` uses the same arbitrary-width whitespace rules to remove whitespace from the start and end. Empty lines with just a newline separator end up as empty strings, which are considered *false* when used in a boolean test such as an `if ...:` condition:

```
if line.strip():
    # line is not empty
```

You could then write that to a new file if you so wish, but that's not really needed *here*.

Answer (score 0):

Just strip the lines to check if they're empty.

```
with open('in.csv', 'r') as fpin, open('out.csv', 'w') as fpout:
    for line in fpin:
        if line.strip():
            fpout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=':')
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```